# Why is my OpenGL program unable to load the GLUT bitmap fonts?

Tags: python, opengl, glut, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I want to display some simple text on the HUD of my 3D environment in OpenGL.
All sources say that I should use the bitmap fonts included in GLUT, however, my program can't seem the find/load the fonts.

I have included all of the correct libraries and have double checked that the fonts.py file is definitely in the ...\Python37\...\OpenGL\GLUT\ directory, but when I type `GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24` (or any of the other bitmap fonts), it is highlighted as an error in my code.

This is the function I call to display the text:

```py
def text(self, x, y, r, g, b, text):

    glColor3f(r, g, b)

    glRasterPos2f(x, y)

    for i in range(len(text)):
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, text[i])
```

And this is how I call the function:

```py
epoch_str = "Epoch: {0}".format(self.epoch)

self.text(x, y, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, epoch_str)
```

As mentioned, the `GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24` is highlighted in my IDE (PyCharm) as an error, and I get the following error if I try to run it:

```py
C:\Users\mickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/mickp/PycharmProjects/Test/U_Matrix.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 130, in safeCall
    return function( *args, **named )
  File "C:/Users/mickp/PycharmProjects/Test/U_Matrix.py", line 142, in render
    self.text(x, y, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, epoch_str)
  File "C:/Users/mickp/PycharmProjects/Test/U_Matrix.py", line 79, in text
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, text[i])
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
GLUT Display callback <bound method U_MATRIX.render of <__main__.U_MATRIX object at 0x000002877FF45438>> with (),{} failed: returning None argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I really don't understand what the problem could be?

Edit: The above error has been fixed, it was a separate problem. The underlying problem with `GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24`is still there. See:
[IDE shows an error for `GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlYBm.png)

Edit 2: Full Code (it's not too long):

Edit 3: Removed full code (it was too long). Adding the following fixed my problem:

```py
# added before
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()
gluOrtho2D(0.0, width, 0.0, height)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()

# these two lines were here
epoch_str = "Epoch: {0}".format(self.epoch)
self.text(x+10, y+10, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, epoch_str)

# added after
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPopMatrix()
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPopMatrix()
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

The text was actually just hidden as I had rendered it into the 3D environment behind an object, as opposed to in front of the 3D environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not the 1st parameter `GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24`, but it is the 2nd parameter `text[i]`.  The parameter to [`glutBitmapCharacter`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glutBitmapCharacter.html) has to be an integral value (`int`), which represents the character.
The chracter has to be converted to an ordinary number (`int`) by [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```py
glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, ord(text[i]))
```

or

```py
for c in text:
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, ord(c))
```

---

If the text doesn't appear on the screen, then reset the projection and model view matrix and draw the text at position (0, 0) for debug reasons:

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()

self.text(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, epoch_str)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPopMatrix()

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPopMatrix()
```

See also [Immediate mode and legacy OpenGL](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python_legacy.md)

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the error it was throwing, but the original problem is unfortunately still there. The program now compiles and runs with no errors, but the text I want displayed is completely missing, and `GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24` is still highlighted as an error in the IDE.

Comment: @Mick_17 Possibly, but I can't fix this, because can't see the rest of your code. `GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24` is no further issue. Of course I tested the code and it works fine for me. What is the matrix setup? Try `x=0` and `y=0`.

Comment: `x=0` and `y=0` didn't work :( I added the full code if you want to have a look...

Comment: @Mick_17 This far to much code. Try the code form the answer, to test your function.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the problem, thanks for the help! I tried your code and it displayed the text in the middle of the 3D environment, without rendering the 3D object. So I think it was there the whole time, just hidden.

Comment: Fixed it by changing to gluOrtho2D()

Comment: @Mick_17 Note, you can push and pop the matrices by `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`. Try new code from the answer.

Comment: Thanks :) accepted yours, can’t vote as I don’t have the privilege level yet

Comment: @Mick_17 Thank you, I'm pleased to help you. You're welcome.